# Setting up Sass using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have sass, compass, bundler, ruby and rails installed on my windows machine.

I've been following the steps at https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

a. Ruby on Rails

I have added the gems in the Gemfile...

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gemspec

# Compass for the dummy app
gem 'compass', require: false

group :development do
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri_21, require: false
end

# Adding bootstrap gem
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
```

When I run the bundle install command I receive:

```
➤  bundle install

Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.
Gemfile syntax error compile error
on line 6: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
gem 'compass', require: false

                   ^
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: what is your ruby version?? try :require => false

Comment: my ruby version is 1.8.7 and rails is 3.0.0

Comment: that worked, but now have syntax error on line 9

Comment: do the same :require => false

Comment: I think it's a syntax issue for 1.8.7..whenever you see a `key: :value` pair..do `:key => :value` instead..are you following the tutorial for the same version of ruby and rails??

Comment: now I'm receving a new error on - bundle install                               You cannot specify the same gem twice with different version require
You specified: bootstrap-sass (>= 0) and bootstrap-sass (~> 3.2.0)

Comment: check your Gemfile you might have some gem that installs bootstrap-sass as dependency..you can try `bundle install` by commenting `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'` (not sure if it works..hit and trial)

Comment: please do not use "bootstrap" as tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" instead as they mean different

Comment: I managed to install all, the ruby way. So I have sass, ruby, devkit, rails and bundler installed. If I choose to start a rails app I will be able to sass my way. Question now is how to intergrate sass into an exsisting project the compass way?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the new `key: value` has syntax introduced in Ruby 1.9. You can't do that in Ruby 1.8. Ruby  [1.8 is also deprecated](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/06/30/we-retire-1-8-7/), you should really stop using it. You're going to be learning the wrong things in a dead version of the language.